# Displaying records in Same Gridview when Search Button in particular panel is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 Panels on one page(SAPInfo, OSInfo).  In SAPInfo panel there are 3 textboxes(SID, Client,User_id) and 1 SEARCH button. After clicking SEARCH button i want to display data of SAP table(user_id,Descriptio,sap_system_password) in Gridview on the next page. Similarly In OSInfo panel there are 2 text boxes(IP/HostName,User_id) and 1 SEARCH button. After clicking SEARCH button i want to display data of OS table(user_id,Descriptio,os_system_password) in the same Gridview. The Gridview has 4 columns(UserID,Description,Password,Change Password)  SAP table contains fields as(sid,client_no,user_id,sap_system_password,description)  OS table contains fields as(user_id,ip,host_name,os_system_password,description)
  How to do this? Please help..
this is my Search button(SAP) code

```
protected void btnSAPSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(clsUser.connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string strQuery = "select DISTINCT user_id,description,sap_system_password from sap_password_info where user_id is not null";
            if (txtSid.Text !="")
            {
                strQuery += " AND sid = '" + txtSid.Text + "'";
            }
            if (txtClient.Text != "")
            {
                strQuery += " AND client_no = '" + txtClient.Text + "'";
            }
            if (txtUser.Text != "")
            {
                strQuery += " AND user_id = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            }

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
            Session["userinfo"] = dt;
            Response.Redirect("~\\PasswordInformation_Details.aspx");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //lblMessage.Text = DataObjects.Error_Message();
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Correct me this is all you want to do. There are some query and based upon those search query you want to display data in GridView in Next page ?

Comment: @Anand  Yes. Records should be displayed only in one GridView depending on search particular query.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple. Pass the search criteria as query string to your other page.
So on click of search button(SAP Panel) build a query string like following

```
 //if sap
    string url = "Result.aspx?Mode=SAP&sid=some_sid&client=some_client&user_id=some_user_id;
    Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

So on click of search button(OS Panel)

```
//if OS
string url = "Result.aspx?Mode=OS&ip=some_ip&user_id=some_userId;
Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

ON result page page_load

```
if(Request.QueryString["Mode"] =="SAP")
{
    //bring sap result dataset
}
else
{
    // bring os result dataset
}

//bind it to gridView
resultGridView.DataSource = dsResult
resultGridView.DataBind();
```

Keep in mind. make the autogeneratedcolumn = true on the grid view. Now your grid view would display whatever result would be given to it(3 column, 4 columns).The columns would be dynamically generated now.

### EDIT 1

After search, you would have some dataset with the result. To change the grid header, simply change the column name in the dataTable. What ever column you would give, would be displayed by the grid

```
datatable.Columns["original_column_name"].ColumnName = "new column name";

//For adding a new column, just simply do this to your result set
datatable.Columns.Add("Change Password");
```

**EDIT 2**

```
string strQuery = "select DISTINCT user_id as User Id,description as Description,sap_system_password as Sap System Password from sap_password_info where user_id is not null";
```

Also see this : [Column Alias](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/column-alias.php)

Comment: Hey But i have given Headings to columns of grid.. i dont want to generate columns automatically, because there is one column named Change Password which is not from any table..

Comment: Do not worry about heading. What ever would be your name of columns in the dataset that would be displayed. See my edit

Comment: That is what i dont want Anand. because the name of columns in DB are short and i want them to display in gridview with proper names. and what about 4th column? and also in ur query string some_sid etc.. means what?

Comment: See, you could change the name of the column by 2 ways. One is the way I have shown above. The other is when you are building you select query you could use "as" operator select some_id as ID, user_id as User Id......

Comment: The 4th column, you would be adding pro grammatically in the datatable. See the code that I have written for it

Comment: see my search button code for SAP in question i have edited.  Now tel me what should i do?

Comment: So now it is needed to write these lines? string url = "Result.aspx?Mode=SAP&sid=some_sid&client=some_client&user_id=some_user_id;     Response.Redirect(url, false);

Comment: Try it and see its working or not. Remeber Result.aspx is a new page :D